# How to use boolean attributes in React without getting warnings and without becoming verbose?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Let's say I want to create a table component.

In my `<th>` elements I want to let the developer specify `start` or `end` to align the text.

We have these options:

```
<th start="true">Title</th>
```

This works, but it's verbose.

We can change it to:

```
<th start>Title</th>
```

This also works, but we get this warning:

> Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `start`.
> If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: start="true" or start={value.toString()}.

But the `<th start>` is very elegent, clean, minimal and it's compatible with HTML's boolean attributes.

How can we have a boolean attribute in react, without getting warnings and without using boilerplate code?

Comment: id need a little more info to help u fix this issue.
- Are u using styled components?
- This `th` component is the normal `html` tag, you meant to do it with your own React component?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not a good idea to have (multiple) boolean props on the same component. For every new boolean prop you add, you have to consider how it might affect all other boolean props. For example, it's not obvious what should happen if someone uses the component like so:

```
<MyTh start="true" end="true"> ... </MyTh>
```

Now imagine what happens if you dare add a third prop. This explodes in complexity.

I would suggest you combine this into a single prop called `textAlignment`, or whatever it is that it represents. The usage would then look like so:

```
<MyTh textAlignment="start"> ... </MyTh>

...

<MyTh textAlignment="end"> ... </MyTh>
```

Comment: Yeah, you're suggestion is good. But let's say for any reason we do need it. And we prevent cluttering in other ways. What's the answer in that case?